# how do I update an entity with a collection navigation property (with MVC2)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-2, entity-framework-4

I am writing an application using MVC2 and EF4. I have created entities from my Database, I have a Timesheet table and a TimesheetEntry table.

I am using the Model binding features of MVC2 and successfully receiving a Timesheet object with its TimesheetEntries populated with the TimesheetEntries created by the user.

If I use the technique I have used in other methods (here timesheet is the object created by the MVC framework):

```
Timesheet temp = context.Timesheets
                    .Include("TimesheetEntries")
                    .Where(t => t.Id == timesheet.Id).First();
context.ApplyCurrentValues<Timesheet>(temp.EntityKey.EntitySetName, timesheet);
context.SaveChanges();
```

Then my TimesheetEntries are not saved.

I have been trying without any success to do this by other means, like deleting all the entries:

```
Timesheet temp = context.Timesheets
       .Include("TimesheetEntries")
       .Where(t => t.Id == timesheet.Id).First();

context.ApplyCurrentValues<Timesheet>(temp.EntityKey.EntitySetName, timesheet);

context.ExecuteStoreCommand(@"DELETE FROM TimesheetEntry WHERE Timesheet=" + timesheet.Id.ToString());
foreach (TimesheetEntry entry in timesheet.TimesheetEntries)
{
    entry.Timesheet = timesheet.Id;
    context.TimesheetEntries.AddObject(entry);
}
context.SaveChanges();
return Redirect("ListTimesheets?PersonnelId="+timesheet.Person);
```

This is not working properly, I am still not getting TimesheetEntries into the DB :-( Just wondering if iam barking up the wrong tree here all together?

P.S. if any one want more info on any of these things let me know. and I can post more code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

again here timesheet is the class created by the MVC mapping

```
Timesheet DBTimesheet = context.Timesheets
                    .Include("TimesheetEntries")
                    .Where(t => t.Id == timesheet.Id).First();

//Delete if in database but not in submission
DBTimesheet.TimesheetEntries
   .Where(dbE => !timesheet.TimesheetEntries.Any(e => e.Id == dbE.Id)).ToList()
   .ForEach(dbE => context.TimesheetEntries.DeleteObject(dbE));

//Update if in submission and in database
timesheet.TimesheetEntries
    .Where(e => DBTimesheet.TimesheetEntries.Any(dbE => dbE.Id == e.Id)).ToList()
    .ForEach(e => context.TimesheetEntries.ApplyCurrentValues(e));

//Add if in submission but not in database
timesheet.TimesheetEntries
    .Where(e => !DBTimesheet.TimesheetEntries.Any(dbE => dbE.Id == e.Id)).ToList()
    .ForEach(e => DBTimesheet.TimesheetEntries.Add(e));

context.SaveChanges();
```

Updates, Deletes and Adds referenced classes as required, NOT FULLY TESTED

Comment: I tested it and it works perfectly. I had to change `context.TimesheetEntries.ApplyCurrentValues(e)` on update section to `((IObjectContextAdapter)context).ObjectContext.ApplyCurrentValues("TimesheetEntries", e));` for EF6.

Answer (score 3):

Read the documentation for `ApplyCurrentValues`; it does scalar properties only.

But you can do:

```
Timesheet temp = context.Timesheets
                    .Include("TimesheetEntries")
                    .Where(t => t.Id == timesheet.Id).First();
context.ApplyCurrentValues<Timesheet>(temp.EntityKey.EntitySetName, timesheet);
foreach(var tse in timesheet.TimesheetEntries)
{
    temp.TimesheetEntries.Add(tse); // or update, if need be.
}
context.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: Wickedly good. Thanks, I think you have highlighted something very good there. It's not exactly working at the moment but I am going to try a few things out.  Good point about reading more, I will defiantly have to do that ;-)